# weakSelf as an iVar

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, weak-references

I'm aware of the fact that you should use weakSelf in block that may survive yourself to avoid retain memory cycle.
like:

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
self.block = ^{
    [weakSelf something];
}
```

But I'm trying to find a generic way. I could use a macro like:

```
#define Weakify(o) __weak __typeof__((__typeof__(o))o)
#define WeakifySelf(o) Weakify(self) o = self;

WeakifySelf(weakSelf)
self.block = ^{
    [weakSelf something];
}
```

Which simplify, but I wonder why I can't use an ivar on my viewController.

```
@interface YDViewController : UIViewController
{
    __weak id _weakSelf;
}
```

and then use this iVar

```
self.block = ^{
    [_weakSelf something];
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue that sinks this idea is that `[_weakSelf something]` is, under the hood, exactly the same as `[self->_weakSelf something]`.

So even though you're trying to use a weak reference, you end up using the strong reference to get to the weak reference and capturing both.